# .Net 5 Console Background service exception with DI of Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have a .NET 5 console application that I am trying to use as a Windows Service which is in the form of a background service now. I have all of the dependency injection setup and working for appsettings and logging just fine. Today, I wanted to add my data into the mix. Here is the structure of my application:

1. I have the Entity Framework Core `DataContext` class all complete.
2. I then created a wrapper, which I will use to create all of my CRUD methods and use within my app. This class is named `DataAccess`.
3. Then, I added the following to my `Program.cs`, `Main` method:

   ```
   services.AddSingleton<DataAccess>();
   services.AddDbContext<MyDataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(ConnnectionString));
   ```
4. Finally, in my `DataAccess` wrapper class, I inject the `DataContext` so I can do my CRUD operations here. Like this:

   ```
    public DataAccess(MyDataContext dataAccess)
    {
        this.dataAccess = dataAccess;
    }
   ```

When I do this and debug, I get the following exception when my app starts:

> Cannot consume scoped service 'ENS.Data.MyDataContext' from singleton 'ENS.Data.DataAccess'.

I know my `DataAccess` wrapper is a singleton and I assume that when you do `services.AddDbContext` that is scoped. So, I sort of understand the error. What I don't understand is I thought you could consume a scoped from a singleton?

What am I doing wrong here or better yet, what is the best way to setup and inject Entity Framework Core `DataContext` into my application for use by my `DataAccess` wrapper and then my `DataAccess` wrapper for use within my whole app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you inject a service inside of another service you need to carefully think of the lifetime of the two services. If you inject service A into service B, then the lifetime of service A must be greater than or equal to the lifetime of service B (because service B will hold a reference on service A, preventing the garbage collector to reclaim the memory allocated for service A).

Based on this rule, you can safely inject a singleton inside of a scoped service, but the opposite is not allowed (because the lifetime of a scoped service is shorter than the lifetime of a singleton service). The violation of this rule leads to an anti pattern known as [captive dependency](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/). If injecting a scoped service into a singleton service were allowed, then the scoped service would become a captive dependency and its lifetime would coincide with the one of the singleton service (put in other words, the injected scoped service would actually become a singleton).

The Microsoft DI container explicitly checks for this anti pattern, this is why  you are getting an error when trying to inject a scoped service into a singleton service.

In your case you have two choices:

1. avoid the data access wrapper class and directly inject the entity framework context where you need it
2. maintain the data access wrapper class and give it a scoped or transient lifetime, so that you can inject the scoped entity framework context into it

As a sidenote, if you need to consume a scoped service from an hosted service class, you can inject the `IServiceScopeFactory` service in the hosted service and use it to create a scope and resolve the scoped service.

Here is an example:

```
public sealed class MyHostedService: BackgroundService 
{
  private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
  
  public MyHostedService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
  {
    _scopeFactory = scopeFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(scopeFactory));
  }
  
  protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
  {
    // ...
  
    using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
      var myScopedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IScopedService>();
      myScopedService.DoWork();
    }
    
    // ....
  }
}
```

You can find more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service)

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response, it was very helpful and educational. I had my thought process backwards which I think is easy to do when trying to wrap your head around this pattern. When not doing DI, you could have a singleton and then consume classes inside (maybe in using statements) so they would be disposed or scoped if you will. I now understand with DI, that changes a bit. There is a good reason I need the wrapper even though others think I should be fired for it, lol. So, I am going to do your option 2 and make it a transient.

Comment: For the record, when I implemented your suggestions, I had a new issue. I am using a background service in this case, where you add it using services.AddHostedService<WindowsBackgroundService>(); and it turns out, it treats this as a singleton too. So, after I fixed my DataAccess wrapper, I was getting a new exception "Cannot consume scoped service 'Ensight.Epic.Data.MyDataContext' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'." However, reading the article your provided for more details here, gave me the answers for this problem. Thanks agian!

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't understand is I thought you could consume a scoped from a
> singleton?

Then here is the explanation: You thought wrong. Your thought actually makes no sense.

- DataAccess is a singleton. There is EVER ONLY ONE.
- The context is inserted into the constructor.

As the context can have multiple - that would mean that the first would be inserted into the data access. YOu would never be able to use another one.

Generally - besides DataAccess as repository being an epic antipattern - there is no sense in injecting the db context UNLESS YOU HAVE ONLY ONE DataAcess instance anyway, and then you could or should have a singleton context too.

The thought makes literally no sense. Now, I would get rid of the DataAccess (or fire you), but that aside, you have 2 ways to handle this:

- Accept you only ever have one data access, inject a singleton dbcontext into it.
- Make both scoped if you need scope.

Comment: thank you for the response and helping me understand what I am doing wrong. Just a comment, for the record, there is no need to be so negative. People are on here because they are having an issue and learning. I don't think telling me several times that I make no sense and that you would fire me, is helpful or constructive for the community here. Please consider a bit more tactful approach to your responses. But again, thank you for the help!